# which framework is good for closed intranet

Tags: openlayers, google-maps, software-recommendations, bing-maps

My requirement is simple. By latitude/longitude, draw icon on the map, draw a line between two icons.I may need put a customer picture over the map.

It is not difficult by google map javascript or bing map javascript.

The problem is that the system is running in a closed intranet environment. No internet access.

Which framework shall I choose? Does it provide map? The system only focus on a specific area, such like a national park, it does not need the map for the whole world.

Answer (score 1):

Before I come to your question, I'll like to explain something about commercial APIs like Google Maps API or the Bing Maps API.

When you use the Google Maps API, you are actually getting 3 different things:

1. Firstly, you are getting a JavaScript Library that you can use in your application or HTML
2. Then you get access to a set of tiles, which are created by Google. The fact that the JavaScript API gives you access to the tiles, is not made clear.
3. You get access to various services like the Geocoding API, or the Directions API through the JavaScript Calls.

---

Now when you use OpenSource libraries, you don't get such a well packaged and integrated solutions.

The Library, be it OpenLayers or Leaflet, is the just the JavaScript Library. You have to take care of the Tiles/maps and the web services if required.

If your application is connected to the internet, you can connect to several online services and get the tiles and maps from there. You could also host your own map services, and consume those.

---

Now coming to your issue. 
You want to draw markers and lines on a map, in an intranet application. Drawing Markers and lines on a map is the easy part, and both OpenLayers and Leaflet have this ability.

Showing a map (which is generally called the basemap) below these markers is the harder part. Since your application is not connected to the internet, you will have to take care of this. You have several options(in increasing order of difficulty):

1. Certain Online services allow you to download their tiles and use them  in your application. You could download the tiles from such a service using an Application like [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net) and then use them in your JavaScript Application.
2. If you have your own data, say in shapefiles, you could create a WMS service based on that data, using a software like Geoserver
3. You could use data from OpenStreetMaps to create your own basemap using a software like tilemill. You can then host these tiles along with your application in your intranet.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the 3rd solution make sense to me. I am going to try openStreetMaps and create my own map!